# About distributivity of a semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, semiring

I know that if $(R, +, ., 0, 1)$ is an idempptent semiring and $x, y\in R,$ then by distributivity of $\cdot$ over $+$, we can write $x+xy+x=x(1+y+1)=x.1=x.$ This time, if my semiring is $(P(X), \cup, \cap,  \lbrace\emptyset \rbrace, X)$. Then for all $X_1, X_2\in P(X)$, and  replacing $+$ by $\cup$, $\cdot $ by $\cap$ and $1$ by $X$ in the above equation, we get $X_1\cup (X_1\cap X_2)\cup X_1=X_1\cap \lbrace X \cup X_2\cup X  \rbrace=X_1\cap X=X_1,$ where $\cap$ distributes over $\cup$, and $P(X)$ is a power set of $X$. Is this equation correct?

Comment: The first equation is wrong unless 1 +  y = 1.  The second equation is correct because the above condition holds.

Comment: @William Elliot,  Yes $1+y=1$  holds in the first equation.

Comment: Prove it for semirings in general..

Comment: @William Elliot I think, the first equation holds almost in every (both additively and multiplicatively) idempotent semiring. But, it may not hold in general semiring.

Comment: It doesn't.  Perhaps you mean a Boolean ring.

Comment: @William Elliot You are right.  Thanks a lot